# BGA X-Ray Good/Bad voids

Tags: bga

I've had very little experience with BGA X-Rays but know that a void does not mean it is bad solder.  I've got a case where the BGA gets hot and I took a picture to see, 99% of the balls have voids although it seem to still be within tolerance(I think).  Can anyone with more experience able to tell from the picture if the BGA balls are good or bad?

[image]

Comment: Are the black circles the balls?  And are the smaller whitish dots vias?  If they are vias, the light gray around them may be the thermal relief in the underlying copper plane.

Comment: So I guess in that picture I can't see the supposed voids you're asking about.

Comment: For those looking to spot the voids, this page has some highlighted further down: https://www.process-sciences.com/BGA_X-ray_Inspection